# saving class of pixels in a list and passing it to the .m program when user closes the labeled matrix image

Tags: matlab, matrix, mouseevent

How can I grab the class of a pixel when I click on it and send it back to my program in an array/list when the user closes the image?

```
h=figure
image(result);
loc=[];
if ishandle(h) ~= 0
    loc(end+1)=get(0, 'PointerLocation');
    pause(0.01)
end

**h = 

  Figure (1) with properties:
  Number: 1
    Name: ''
   Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
Position: [680 558 560 420]
   Units: 'pixels'
```

Show all properties

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in two_human_new (line 23)
    loc(end+1)=get(0, 'PointerLocation');
 **

Basically I want to capture the Index information as long as user is clicking on the image.
[image]

^this image is result of of image(result)
h =

Figure (2) with properties:

```
  Number: 2
    Name: ''
   Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
Position: [680 558 560 420]
   Units: 'pixels'
```

Show all properties

```
Error using get
There is no Index property on the Root class.

Error in two_human_new (line 23)
    loc(end+1)=get(0, 'Index');
```

Comment: If you initialize something like this `loc=[ ];`, you can store values later on with `loc(end+1)` only if you are storing scalars. e.g. if `loc(end+1) = 1`, it's fine. But if you do something else like this: `loc(end+1) = [1,2]`, you'll get the *dimension mismatch* error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Sardar_Usama noted, you are getting an error because `get(0, 'PointerLocation')` returns an array of two elements.

Modifying `loc` to cell array solves the problem:

Initialization:

```
loc = {};
```

Storing position:

```
loc{end + 1} = get(0, 'PointerLocation');
```

---

Other option is splitting `loc` to `locx` and `locy`:

```
locx = [];
locy = [];
```

Storing:

```
pos = get(0, 'PointerLocation');
locx(end + 1) = pos(1);
locy(end + 1) = pos(2);
```

---

Check if the following code is what you have meant:
I added the `while` loop, so the code keeps running until you close the windows.

```
result = imread('peppers.png');

h=figure;
image(result);
locx = [];
locy = [];

while (ishandle(h))
    pos = get(0, 'PointerLocation'); 
    locx(end + 1) = pos(1);
    locy(end + 1) = pos(2);
    pause(1)
end

%Display locx and locy for debugging.
locx
locy
```

---

I think [ginput](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) is what you are looking for.
There must be a better way than the `try` and 'catch` block I used, but I can't think of right now.

```
result = imread('peppers.png');

h=figure;
image(result);
locx = [];
locy = [];

%set(gca, 'Units', 'pixels');

while (ishandle(h))
    %pos = get(0, 'PointerLocation'); 
    %pos = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint');
    try
        [x, y] = ginput(1);
        locx(end + 1) = x;
        locy(end + 1) = y;
        pause(0.01)        
    catch me
    end
end

locx
locy
```

Comment: I think you should put your code in a while loop. I am not sure what is the purpose of your code. `get(0, 'PointerLocation');` returns the x, y mouse cursor coordinates (in the entire screen).

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do I get the index besides locx and locy? for me basically index matters

Comment: Looks like [ginput](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) is what your are looking for.

Comment: I clicked only on two points but it reports many points >> locx

locx =

         941         941        1038        1134         961         318         842         964        1572        1653        1674        1674        1855

Comment: can you please suggest a fix?

Comment: please have a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353878/grabbing-the-index-value-from-the-pointer-when-clicking-on-the-image-in-matlab I explained the problem further

Comment: This is a followed up question, so please add a link to the above post (original question). I will let someone else try to answer it.