# grabbing the index value from the pointer when clicking on the image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mouseevent, matlab-gui

How can I find the index of a point on click on and add it to end of an array, list or vector?

```
h=figure;
image(result);
locx = [];
locy = [];
while (ishandle(h))
    pos = get(0, 'PointerLocation');
    locx(end + 1) = pos(1);
    locy(end + 1) = pos(2);
    pause(1);
end
```

While I have only clicked on two points to see their x,y and index, many x locations has been saved in locx array. Please suggest solution and fixes:

```
locx =

  Columns 1 through 16

         635        1116         231         758         771         591         596          46         116         116         116        1362         852         498        1920        1663

  Columns 17 through 32

         733         795         795        1920        1895        1806        1061         700         123        1102        1097        1615           1         226         233         233

  Columns 33 through 43

         191         854         836        1920        1920        1920        1920        1920        1905        1189        1912
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`ginput`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) function instead:

```
h = figure;
image(result);
[locx, locy] = ginput(2);
```

This will give you points within the axes, which will have to be converted to indices into the image by rounding them off:

```
locx = round(locx);
locy = round(locy);
```

Comment: how would you write this in the while loop like above as well as the condition to capture only the points one clicks on not the point  that one hovers on? thansk

Comment: Also I am a total newbie, I am not sure how to do the rounding to match the actual points as shown in the images

Comment: @MonaJalal: That's what it does, without the need for a while loop. It will only capture points when you click with the mouse, and the `ginput` function will not return until you have selected 2 points.

Comment: I get this error Interrupted by figure deletion Error using ginput (line 81)
Interrupted by figure deletion

Comment: also how can I change this that goes on until I close the window rather than clicking on 5 points? [locx, locy] = ginput(5);

Comment: @MonaJalal: If you want the window to close after selecting an arbitrary number of points, do this: `[locx, locy] = ginput(); close(h);` After you select the points you want, hit the **Return** key and the window will close.

Comment: Thank you so much! Quite like what I was looking for. Amazing!